# Can I take a Schengen visa for business trip to Germany

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, uk-residents

I'm planning on a one-day business trip to Germany and my company asked me to apply for a Schengen visa. Is that a valid one? I thought that the Schengen visa is applicable only for the tourist, Please clarify. And, how long does it generally take to get the visa in hand? I'm an Indian passport holder with a UK Work Permit and I will be applying from the UK.

Comment: You will need a Schengen short-stay for a trip to *talk about* business, or a German long-stay visa to *actually do the work* in Germany. One day sounds very much like a trip to talk about business.

Comment: Who will be paying you when you are there? Is it your UK company, or the company you are visiting? For the former you need a business visa; for the later a work visa

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.

Comment: Hello All, thanks for the answers and suggestions. I have got the Schengen VISA from London and successfully completed a week-long trip to Germany